# Rails Active Storage not display @user.banner_image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

So I've been playing with rails active storage lately and came across an issue.

```
user.rb
```

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :banner_image
end
```

---

```
show.html.haml
```

```rb
.profile-header
  = @user.banner_image
```

in return i get this error:

```
Can't resolve image into URL: to_model delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil
Extracted source (around line #2):

.profile-header
  = image_tag @user.banner_image

.listings
  - @listings.each do |listing|
    .box
```

What am I doing wrong? 
I permitted the banner_image in the user controller by the way. and i have active storage installed.

Answer (score 0):

It shoud be:

```
.profile-header
  = image_tag url_for(@user.banner_image)
```

Comment: gives me to_model delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil

Answer (score 0):

You must tell Active Storage which service to use by setting `Rails.application.config.active_storage.service`

Store files locally

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

Comment: is this all into the development.rb?

Comment: I have this already set. gives me to_model delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil