# to_model delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I asked this question already here:
[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58002952/rails-active-storage-not-display-user-banner-image)
and didn't get much help, I looked for other questions similar to mine, but no resolution. So I'll ask the question again in hopes of getting help.
The issue is that the image that is uploaded for a user profile banner isnt showing on the user show page aka profile page. I'm using active storage. I already have the

> has_on_attached :banner_image

```
.profile-header
  = image_tag url_for(@user.banner_image)
```

```rb
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

devise registration config:

```rb
def configure_account_update_params
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:firstname, :banner_image])
end
```

[error msg image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9dv6.png)

Terminal reads when refreshing the profile page:

```
Started GET "/users/1" for ::1 at 2019-09-20 21:51:59 -0700
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:11
  Rendering users/show.html.haml within layouts/application
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 1], ["record_type", "User"], ["name", "banner_image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/users/show.html.haml:2
  Listing Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/users/show.html.haml:5
  Rendered users/show.html.haml within layouts/application (5.5ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/layouts/_navigation.html.haml:18
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.haml (8.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 61ms (Views: 57.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? That the code raises an error when there is no photo attached? Why don't you check before creating the link? Or did you double-check and the image exist?

Comment: @spickermann the issue is the images do no load on the users show view.

Answer (score 1):

**ISSUE RESOLVED:**

```
  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:firstname, :image])
  end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:firstname, :image])
  end
```

so the **configure_account_update_params** defenition was set to permit the :signup not :account_update. I changed it to :account_update and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have a banner image for the user.  If your view layout breaks because the user has no banner so use conditional `if` in your code

```
image_tag url_for(@user.banner_image) if @user.banner_image.present?
```

Or you may want to have a fallback image to preserve the layout

```
image_tag url_for(@user.banner_image || '/public/fallback_banner_image.jpg')
```

The above line is an example but you will need to include an actual file image/path

Comment: yes, but the issue is not this, the issue is that no matter if i upload the image for the banner, it doesnt load it.